# Reference point in Laplace's equation

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, conventions

I have been learning about how we go about solving Laplace's equation when we want to find the potential for some region with no charge. My question is, is it implicitly considered here that the reference point with respect to which we measure the potential is kept at infinity?

Answer (score 0):

The reference point does not have to be at infinity. For example, you can have the classic problem of a box with conducting sides where one side (or sides) of the box is grounded and the other sides have some non-zero potential relative to ground.

In general you can set the zero-point anywhere though.

Answer (score 0):

No, the reference point can be at any arbitrary finite position. Of course it is suitable to choose it in a way that it benefits from the symmetry -- if any -- of the problem. The important aspect of such a problem is that the boundary conditions -- Dirichlet or Neumann or a mix of it -- are not completely zero.